# shorter way for site visit evidence

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple visit evidence for my site, and it seems I need three different files:

`- count_01.php`- for processing data
`- count_02.php` - for writing data
`- counter.php` - for displaying data

`count_01.php` - included in each page:

```
$date = date("d. m. H:i");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($ip == "127.0.0.1" or $ip == "31.176.166.1") {return false;}  // my ip

$book = "inc/count_02.php";
$a = file_get_contents($book);
$b = "<span class='date'>" . $date . "</span>" . "<span class='ip'>" . $ip . "</span>" . "\n<br><br>\n";
$c = $a . $b;
file_put_contents($book, $c);
```

`count_02.php` is then included in `counter.php`, inside a specific div.

It seems this works, but is there a shorter way?

For example is it possible to write data directly inside a specific div in `counter.php` and save the file.

Or any other solution.

Comment: Why would you need multiple files to do something that can be done in one?

Comment: @putvande, this is my question - HOW?

Comment: Just put your code in on file.

Comment: @putvande, you say that I can read/write a file from the file itself?

Comment: You are writing to a file. Why not use a database? But I guess if you use a file to write to, you need at least two, don't know why you would need 3

Comment: @putvande, because by `$a = file_get_contents($book);` the ending `body` and `html` tags are included. And when I add new visit data, this tags are moved before new data, and that's not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a function.

```
function print_book($book) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if ($ip == "127.0.0.1" or $ip == "31.176.166.1") {
        return false;
    } // my ip

    $date = date("d. m. H:i");
    $a = file_get_contents($book);
    $b = "<span class='date'>" . $date . "</span>" . "<span class='ip'>" . $ip . "</span>" . "\n<br><br>\n";
    return $a . $b;
}
```

counter.php

```
…
…
<div> <?php print_book("inc/count_02.php"); ?> </div>
…
```

Comment: jurgemaiste, thanks a lot, but what is `$book` in your code? If it is the `count_02.php` there are three files again. Also the new data will not be saved inside `counter.php` !

Comment: I just arbitrated what in your code is spelled out as `$book = "inc/count_02.php";` so that you can call the `print_book` function with other books than `count_02.php`. So you could in theory call `print_book("inc/other_book.php")`. Why do you need to save the data inside counter.php?

Comment: because it is the purpose of evidence.

Comment: Oh right. I just read your comments to the question. Sounds like you need a database to save the data. PHP is for logic and HTML is for presentation. It's not a place you would want to save your data.